# Error in invoking javac - Debian Squeeze

Tags: debian-squeeze, java

I am trying to solve this issue:
PWC6345: There is an error in invoking javac.  A full JDK (not just JRE) is required

We have a third-party Java app that uses a Jetty server but looks like either the JDK is missing or not reachable where it is located?

In /usr/bin I see:

java
javaws
jexec

No javac so probably no JDK installed.

The box is Debian "Squeeze" with the following:

java -version
java version "1.6.0_18"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.8.13) (6b18-1.8.13-0+squeeze2)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode, sharing)

What is this the right Squeeze package?
apt-cache search javac
**default-jdk - Standard Java or Java compatible Development Kit**
**openjdk-6-jdk - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)**
**Something else?**
Thanks!

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /. Reason:

PWC6345: There is an error in invoking javac.  A full JDK (not just JRE) is required

Caused by:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6345: There is an error in invoking javac.  A full JDK (not just JRE) is required
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:378)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:119)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Jsr199JavaCompiler.compile(Jsr199JavaCompiler.java:208)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:384)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:453)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:625)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:598)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:486)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:542)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1065)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:413)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:999)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:271)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:98)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:557)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:598)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:486)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1065)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:413)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:999)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:250)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:350)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:454)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:890)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:944)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:630)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:77)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:620)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:46)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:603)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:538)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, depending on the web application you want to run in Jetty, it might be better to install the Sun JDK ( sun-java6-jdk , which would automatically divert all java/javac/... symbolic link to the Sun JDK ), because it often provides a much better compatibility with some applications.

The default-jdk should at least provide javac, so the error might indicate that you have a compatibility issue (It does NOT say that javac could not be found, but that javac failed to execute correctly).

Answer (score 2):

The error log already shows the problem:
A **full** JDK (not just JRE) is required

I'd recommend to select default-jdk

Comment: I also found: sun-java6-jdk - Sun Java(TM) Development Kit (JDK) 6. Would you still recommend default-jdk?

Comment: As this one is the "most original" JDK I then would recommend you to use this one but I assume that default-jdk is equally.

Comment: OK. Will try that and report back